# quick method of accounting in QuickBooks online

Tags: canada, sales-tax, quebec, quickbooks-online

I use QuickBooks online for accounting.

For collecting sales taxes I choose [Quick method](https://www.revenuquebec.ca/en/businesses/consumption-taxes/gsthst-and-qst/reporting-qst-and-gsthst/the-quick-method-of-accounting-for-calculating-gst-and-qst-remittances/).

But I don't know how I can use it in QuickBooks online.

I found [the following question on Quickbooks forum](https://community.intuit.com/questions/1558072-how-do-i-record-the-hst-paid-using-the-quick-method):

> client enters sales and expenses net of HST to show HST on invoices,
>   where does credit get posted when pay HST based on quick method, so
>   less than owing per the balance sheet?

And answer:

> QB does not understand the "Quick Method".

But it's answer is two year old.

It's still not possible?

Probably I should contact QuickBooks support and I'll do it, but maybe somebody has some experience in using Quick method in QuickBooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted QuickBooks support and they gave [the following link](https://community.intuit.com/questions/1558072-how-do-i-record-the-hst-paid-using-the-quick-method?fbclid=IwAR1rWopBG3xiXUESVO0tMUXiG1TsvCmwu5vGBZiGj6XozWorAP_uC7xUwsE):

> QB does not understand the "Quick Method".  (Which in any case is not
>   really all that "Quick".)
>
> My recommendation:
>
> Do not track HST on MOST expenses, only on those rare expenditures
>   that qualify for treatment as ITC (Input Tax Credits) under the Quick
>   Method - typically capital expenditures, for example, but research
>   this further for your client's benefit. For most expenses, "operating
>   expenses" according to CRA, the HST paid is just part of the expense.
>
> Calculate the HST "manually" (Sales + HST collected) x rate (remember
>   to reduce the "Quick Method rate" by 1% on the first $30,000).  Then
>   calculate the "discount" (actual amount collected, minus the manual
>   calculation).  Enter the "discount" as a Sales Tax Adjustment using
>   the Sales Tax Item for "Adjustment to HST on Sales".  For the "Sales
>   Tax Adjustment Account" use something like "Miscellaneous Income" -
>   yes, this is income subject to income tax, but then the HST paid on
>   expenses is also part of your deductible expenses.
>
> QB will not correctly report the Sales and Other Revenue (Line 101 on
>   the return) so do not file online directly from QB.  Instead choose
>   "File by Paper or Other Method", then use either NETFILE or paper.

Comment: Link is no longer accessible. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @xlash, yes, they removed it, but I copied context